# Adding 1 to elements of an empty list using another list to count up (maybe with += ?)

Tags: python, list, count

I'm very new to python and programming, so please keep answers simple if you can.

I'm trying to create a script that will add 1 to elements in an empty list based on an unordered other list. My inputs are shown below as well as my desired output. Since 5 appears twice in the 'data' list, element 5 in 'input' should count up to 2.

Here's the code I tried, with the error it gives:

```
input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
data = [5, 1, 2, 5]

input[data] += 1

#desired output: [1, 1, 0, 0, 2]
```

The error this gives:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

I'm confused, because I have a list of integers, but I guess that doesn't count as type 'int'. I searched to try to convert a list to integers, but all the solutions I found result in still having type 'list'. I'm thinking += might not be the right operator to use in this instance, but I'm not sure what else to use.

Edit: Oops, I forgot about lists starting at 0. Thanks for pointing that out, and thanks for all the great answers! Hard to choose just one.

Comment: if an element occurs more than twice? maximum count should be 2?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but yes some elements will occur more than twice in my actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to python!

Your problems arise from a misunderstanding of how indexing works. There are two problems. The first has to do with data types, and is neatly encapsulated in your error message: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`. Let's break this down a bit:

'Indexing' is what happens when you use square brackets after a list to access a particular element of that list. i.e. if `a` is a list, `a[N]` will return the Nth element of a, where N is an integer. You can only access *one* element at a time when indexing. Python doesn't know what to do if you give it a list, and your error message is basically telling you "You've asked me to index a list with another list, and I don't know how to do that. I only understand integers!".

Because you can only index *one* value at time, the best way of doing what you're trying to do is with a loop:

```
for i in data:
    input[i] += 1
```

How is this different from what you've done? Using a loop goes through each element of `data` individually, temporarily calls it `i`, and uses that to index input, and then the `+= 1` does what you were originally trying to do.

**HOWEVER**, if you run the loop, you'll get a second error message, because of a different problem. This error will say `IndexError: list index out of range`, which tells you that you're requesting to access a part of the list that doesn't exist. But why? `input` has 5 items in it, and you're only asking it for indices between 1 and 5! This error arises because Python's indexing starts at zero, not one. Valid indices of the `input` list are therefore `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, *not* `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Because your `data` list contains the number 5, at some point during the loop `i = 5`, and you're asking to access the sixth element of `index` (`index[5]`), which does not exist.

You can get past this either by changing your `data` list so that it contains valid indices, or adjusting your loop so that:

```
for i in data:
    input[i - 1] += 1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: s/fifth element/sixth element/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop through the **data** list, since you cannot pass a list to the index of a list (which is what the error is telling you).

Something like:

```
for ind in data:
    input[ind]+=1
```

Note also that Python lists are 0-indexed, which means the first element is called using:

```
input[0]
```

I notice you have 5's in your **data** list - there is no 5th element in your **input** - the indices are 0,1,2,3,4 so you'd need to modify your code (or **input** list) for it to run without an error.

Answer (score 1):

Python basically is telling you, *you can't use a list as an index to another list*. When you try to index the `input` list with the `data` list, Python raises an error because the index object is not valid(Also, while I'm at it, `input` is a reserved keyword in Python **and should not be used as variable name**. But for sake of clarity, I'll keep using it).

This code

```
input[data] += 1
```

is equivalent to this

```
input[[5, 1, 2, 5]] += 1
```

Which of course makes no sense, and Python complains.

Now if I understand you right, you want to increment the element in `input` which corresponds to the element in `data`, each time an occurrences of the element is found. If this is the case, a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) would be a much better choice.

Each key in the dictionary would the a number from `data`, and the value of each key is zero. Each time an occurrence of a key is found, the corresponding value will be incremented. eg.

```
input = {5: 0, 2:0, 1:0}
data = [5, 1, 2, 5]

for element in data:
    inpt[element] += 1
```

However, a much better idea would be to use the [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [5, 1, 2, 5]
input = Counter(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem before spewing wisdom on how to make it better.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah I do find that pretty annoying sometimes when I ask a question, and some just does a code dump. Code dumps may be useful to the OP at first, but in the long run, your doing more damage then good.

Comment: What does it mean to use a list as an index to another list? I understood index to mean a position in a list, but that doesn't make sense in your context.

Comment: @Liquidity It means your trying to use a list object, to index a list. The fact the that this doesn't sound right is exactly my point. Using a list object to try to index another list _doesn't_ make sense in both the code and the context. Which is why Python raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to speed things up is to use a `collections.Counter` to count the number of times it appeared in data.

```
input = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
data = [5, 1, 2, 5]


from collections import Counter
counted = Counter(data)
for i, b in counted.items():
    input[i-1] = b
```

And as a side note, `input` or any other pre-defined names isn't good variable names since they could mess things up in the future.

A easier way to create the `input` is to do this in case you don't know how many zeroes you need.

```
input = [0 for _ in range(max(a))] # place this after you defined counted
```

And I believe you don't even need to do this, just use the Counter instance can surely get the job done. `Counter({5: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1})` It behaves almost the same way as a dict.

Comment: Why do you use a loop instead of a list comprehension to convert the counter to a list?

Comment: Then why do you advocate  a list comprehension immediately after that, where it probably doesn't belong? If the elements have no dependence on the loop variable, you can do [0]*max(a)

Answer (score 0):

list is accessed by its index
suppose `list1 = [3,4,1,2,5]`
to access list element i need to provide index of that element. index start with 0 to n. suppose i want to access second element of list

```
print list1[1]

#out: 4
```

to iterate through list element

```
for i in list1:
   print list1[i]
```

in your code you are accessing list index by  another list.